# Drop Down Box, show choice in next page

Tags: java, html, database, jsf, glassfish

I am trying to make a drop down box, which gets choices from a database held on a Glassfish server. I have managed to achieve this. The next step was to have the choices from the user appear on the next page. I have attempted to do this by doing this

index.xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{mealBean.monLunch}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mealBean.getMealsByTime('Lunch')}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

There is a command button linking to the results.xhtml from index.xhtml as follows

Bean

```
public String monLunch;
public String monDinner;

public String getMonLunch() {
    return monLunch;
}

public void setMonLunch(String monLunch) {
    this.monLunch = monLunch;
}
public void setMonDinner(String monDinner) {
    this.monDinner = monDinner;
}
public String getMonDinner() {
    return monDinner;
}
```

and then on the results.xhtml

```
#{mealBean.monLunch}
```

My issue is, when I click the command button, the data does not appear on the new page. Is there a way to remedy this? Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Hi. I do not understand why you set monLunch in your xhtml and in your results.xhtml you try to get the monDinner...

Comment: oh sorry, i've corrected it. The results.xhtml tries to display both the choices but i copied the wrong one haha

Comment: If you look at the code generated for your index.xhtml, are the "value" attributes OK in the "option" tags ? Do you have something like <option value="aaa">...</option> ?

Comment: Yeah, all of the options appear in the drop down boxes from the database. They appear on the webpage and when i check the elements in the F12 menu

Comment: What is important is not what you see in the webpage, but the values of the "value" attributes in the option tags. What are the annotations on your bean ? What scope do you use ?

Comment: Just seen your edit, yeah mine appears that way, it says <select name"j_idt5:j_idt10" size=1> <option value="aaa">...</option>....</select>

Comment: Annotations are @Named(value = "mealBean") and @Dependent

Comment: scope is @SessionScoped

Comment: Ok. I think you should try to remove the @Dependent, because it is in conflict with the SessionScoped : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html

Comment: Okay, I removed the '@Dependant' and then when i tried to load the webpage again, the <option> disappeared in my drop down boxes. When I put the '@Dependant' back in and took away the '@Session', they reappeared but with the same issue as before. Thank you for the help

Comment: Hmmmm... :( I do not understand why you need the dependent annotation.  What does return your getMealsByTime ? A List<String> ? What are your imports in the bean ? Can you try to replace Named(value = "mealBean") Dependent SessionScoped by ManagedBean(name = "mealBean") SessionScoped ?

Comment: That actually fixed it haha changing the '@Named' to '@ManagedBean' With the '@SessionScoped'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good. Then I will write an "Answer" to your question :)

Comment: This information needs to be in the question, otherwise people looking at this answer will not understand your @ValBonn's answer unless they read all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate your bean with `@ManagedBean(name = "mealBean")` instead of `@Named(value = "mealBean")`.

It is not a good practice to mix CDI annotations like `javax.inject.Named` with the JSF annotations, like `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` or `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`.

And this way you can delete the useless `@Dependent`.